# My account has repeated serial upvotes - what's going on?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Looks like as I have got three different types of clean up on my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel?tab=reputation) after [Serial up voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129442/serial-up-voting)

1. `13/apr/2012` and `16/apr/2012` (Serial upvoting reversed on next day)
2. `19/apr/2012` (Serial upvoting reversed on next day)
3. from `yesterday` (Serial upvoting reversed on today)

Can anyone explain why this is happening to my account?

Comment: If you're getting serial-voted repeatedly, you might want to flag down a moderator (by flagging one of your posts, or via the [chat]) and ask them to look into it. Creating more meta topics doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: What's with the underscores?

Comment: Is there a question in all of this, or are you basically stating that the system works?

Comment: Hello there, I've edited your question to ask a question (what's going on) - if that's not the intent of your question can you please edit it (edit link under Q) and correct what I've added - I've just assumed you're wondering why this is happening.

Comment: @lunboks not much a moderator can do about it unless it's a voting ring...and people don't usually report their own voting rings

Comment: btw and I flagged this issue

Comment: @Bart only about how different this engine works

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you have a "superfan" who continues to upvote your posts all out of proportion to other users' posts.  As the upvotes from this one user accumulate, they're being invalidated by an automated process that looks for voting irregularities.  I'll send the user a private message asking them to stop.

Comment: this automated engine generated different process how to take `Serial upvoting reversed` on next days

Comment: @TheEstablishment No, I sent them a private message myself.  Moderators can't normally see what anyone is voting for, but we can if very suspicious voting patterns emerge.

Comment: Ah, duh. I guess for whatever reason I read `I'll` as `It'll`. Sorry!