# Serial Up-voting and Reputation Cap

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, serial-voting

I've just been the 'victim' of some serial up-voting:

[image]

This has pushed me over the rep cap for the day, so any other up-votes I receive today won't 'earn' the rep so-to-speak.

My question is this: What happens when these serial up-votes are inevitably reversed when the midnight script runs? At what point do those votes that previously *didn't* count towards my reputation get converted into actual reputation points? Is it automatic, or after a reputation re-calc, etc.?

I realise there are plenty of questions about serial up-voting on this site, but after trawling through most (all?) of them I couldn't find one that discussed how the rep cap is affected by the reversal.

I know I could just wait and see what happens but I'm impatient ;)

Comment: When you *do* get an answer, it needs to be added to the [FAQ regarding serial voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). If you don't want to add it yourself, ping me so that I remember to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure why would someone other than yourself with a duplicate account would start voting on all your questions.

Comment: @fofole Me neither. But if I *was* serial up-voting myself...do you think I'd report it here? ;) This is quite common apparently, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129983/my-account-has-repeated-serial-upvotes-whats-going-on

Comment: @Clive dunno maybe to have an alibi :) But it's not like I was accusing you or anything. I was just wondering.

Comment: @Fofole Hard to imagine someone would go to those lengths just to get a few rep points, but it's a crazy world! I didn't take what you said as accusatorial by the way, I probably would have said the same thing :)

Comment: Serial upvoting *does* happen in non-sockpuppet situations. People really appreciate an answer you've given them, and in an attempt to "reward" you, they go through and upvote a bunch of your other answers. The system catches their attempts and invalidates all of their votes. There was nothing sinister going on there, just someone unfamiliar with the system trying to show a little gratitude. The proper action would have been to set a bounty. (cc @Fofole)

Comment: +1 I upvoted your question, but in doing so feel I may have become part of the problem...

Comment: @TheEstablishment Will do

Comment: @TheEstablishment Added to the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857), please feel free to improve

Comment: [whodis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/604554/clive)

Comment: @Won't Wow, didn't even know I had that account (it's definitely me, I'm the only Clive at that company!) I kinda feel like I've done something wrong now! Should I ask somewhere for that account to be deleted? It's not been used in over a year

Comment: @Clive: I tried to merge, but your rep prevents mere mods from doing this.  Supposedly a dev has been notified.  If you care, you can email team@stackoverflow and request a merge.

Comment: @Won't completely off-topic - does the contact form on your web site still work? Just asking because the last entry on your blog is 2 years old, and I know I've neglected contact forms on *my* ancient sites :)

Comment: @Pekka: No idea.  I'm planning on moving off my current host in the next two weeks, and to start dumping stuff I've been saving.  Why you ask?

Comment: @Won't if everything works out, I'll be traveling the US in Aug/Sep/Oct. I wanted to know which state you live in, and if it's on my route, whether you're up for a beer.

Comment: @Pekka: South Carolina, and I'd love to show you the American beers we *don't* ship overseas.

Comment: @Will great!! Could you throw an E-Mail address at me so I can contact you once my plans mature?

Comment: So it is still going on... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64255/6309

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What happens when these serial up-votes are inevitably reversed when the midnight script runs?

The serial upvotes get reversed, all other votes count as normal from that point on.

Think of it as "the serial upvotes never happened"...

Comment: When you say "from that point on", do you mean that only votes cast *after* the reversal will count towards reputation? Or that all votes that did not previously count towards reputation will also then count towards reputation?

Comment: @Clive: your rep will be recalculated as if the serial votes had never happened at all. There will be no before/after, they cease to exist.

Comment: @Mat Great thanks. I know this sounds like I'm worrying over a few rep points but that's really not the case; just interested to know what happens :)

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I just became the victim of a serial upvote, too.

Comment: Would you please take a look at my situation [in here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/why-reputation-is-locked-after-a-serial-up-voting). I had the same issue but thing does not match as you have said here. I added the details.