# Triggering reputation recalculation should trigger fraud calculations too

Tags: feature-request, reputation, serial-voting, reputation-recalc

Someone just upvoted a great deal of my answers, and so these votes will be removed at the end of the day. I tried to trigger recalculation myself so they could be removed right away, but it didn't work.

I'd prefer that the recalc calculated the fraudulent upvotes away too, if that's feasible.

As a side note, does this affect reputation cap? Like I can't gain reputation today because the system doesn't know yet if the reputation cap was reached through fraudulent upvotes.

Comment: What's wrong with just waiting until the script runs?

Comment: @Bart that depends on the answer to the side note

Comment: @Esailija The rep cap is recalculated when there's a serial voting reversal.

Comment: See [Serial Up-voting and Reputation Cap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131795/serial-up-voting-and-reputation-cap)

Comment: @Yannis right, then it's just a question of convenience. I would prefer not see the upvote pollution that I know is going to be removed but still shows up. I totally understand if this isn't feasible to do because of that reason :P

Comment: The serial voting detection and reversal is a totally independent job running daily at 3 AM according to the reversals time stamps. Once the job found serial voting and reversed it it's triggering recalc but I don't think it should work in both directions.

Comment: @Esailija: You prefer not to see the pollution? Well, even if it gets reversed, it's still all listed there in your profile. So I don't see how this gets rid of any pollution.

Comment: @animuson I mean when I hover over my profile link, legit upvotes are mixed with the fraudulent ones.

Comment: @animuson actually I just noticed I don't even see new upvotes (as I am fraudulently capped) without going into my profile vote history, which is really inconvenient, especially when it takes 10 seconds for my profile to load for some reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the feature to trigger reputation recalculation no longer exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being able to trigger the fraud check at will would make it significantly easier to find out the exact thresholds that trigger it. I think this disadvantage is not worth it to gain a bit of convenience.

As far as I know the serial voting reversal will also recalculate the repuation as if those votes never happened, so there should be no disadvantage due to hitting the rep cap to you.

Comment: Interesting note on the reverse engineering... didn't think of that. This feature would actually make it easier for voting frauds to stick and as a rep whore I don't want that.

Comment: Recalcs are only allowed once every UTC day.  Which makes it impossible to exploit, the daily fraud script execution is also daily so provides the same insight.  The request has merit, it simply gets the fraud script running earlier.

Comment: @UphillLuge - the self recalc will likely be removed in the future (as it's no longer needed - this happens automatically), and it's *not* impossible to exploit because of its interval, it just somewhat throttles discovery.